# Rotating SVG element that has existing rotation with snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, rotation, snap.svg

When I'm using snap.svg to animate rotation on element that has a rotation already i get all kinds of problems.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aOrrVz

```
var s = Snap.select("#Layer_1");
var rect1 = s.select("#rect1");
var rect2 = s.select("#rect2");
var oldRotate = rect2.transform().localMatrix.split().rotate;

this.spin = function() {
 rect1.animate({transform:'r90,161.8,152.4'},1000, function(){
  rect1.animate({transform:'r0,161.8,152.4'},1000);
 });


 rect2.animate({transform:'r-90,435.2,168.9'},1000, function(){
  rect2.animate({transform:'r'+oldRotate+',435.2,168.9'},1000);
 });
}
```

If you look at the codepen you can see that the blue rectangle does not behave like the other one, it drops down a little and seems to interpolate between two different states when animating. I'm guessing this has something to do with the matrix, but i don't really know how do deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that whilst split() will indeed tell you a rotation, it won't actually tell you the rotation that you may think it does.

The best way to do these animations is to control the values yourself, rather than splitting matrices which will cause enormous headaches when it comes to animation.

If there's a case where its an element that has a transform already which you don't really know, then maybe the best bet would be to place it in a group and transform that group.